# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-templates

I am getting error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

I have included below js files

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
```

and my js code is

```
angular.module('website',['ngRoute','ngResource']).
     config(function($routerProvider){
        $routerProvider.
            when('/about',{template:'templates/about.html'}),
            when('/careers',{template:'templates/careers.html'}),
            when('/signup',{template:'templates/signup.html'}),
            otherwise({redirectTo : '/home', template:'/home.html'})
    })

function mainController($scope){

}
```

Somebody please help me, where i am missing.

**EDITED:**
Error log is 
Failed to instantiate module website due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24ro...
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:40:307
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:38:308)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:39:64)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:37:279)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:37:403
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:37:180)
    at eb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:40:435

Comment: Two things: 1) It looks like you are referencing different versions of each Angular library. Pick one version and use it for all references. 2) When you are debugging do not use the minified versions. Using non-minified versions when debugging will give you far more detailed error messages.

Comment: can you post your whole error log??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/619lZC5u7ayvIktBc20t?p=preview)

Change `$routerProvider` to `$routeProvider`. Replace `,` with `.` in config. For example:

```
when('/about',{template:'templates/about.html'}),
when('/careers',{template:'templates/careers.html'})
```

to

```
when('/about',{template:'templates/about.html'})
.when('/careers',{template:'templates/careers.html'})
```

Your JavaScript code should look like this:

```
var website = angular.module('website',['ngRoute','ngResource']);

     website.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/about',{template:'templates/about.html'})
            .when('/careers',{template:'templates/careers.html'})
            .when('/signup',{template:'templates/signup.html'})
            .otherwise({redirectTo : '/home', template:'/home.html'})
    }) 

website.controller('mainController', function($scope){

});
```

For more information, [please have a look at this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example).

Hope that solve your problem.